# css - how to use part of image as background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use part of an image as background for a div.

It works for my fixed width screen.

[image: desired output]

But when I resize the screen width, it loses correct position, showing other parts of image.

[image: behavior while resizing]

Someone can help?

HTML

```
<div class="game">
  <div class="slice top_estrada"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.game{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  .slice{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('/assets/maps/tilemaps/mymap.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    &.top_estrada{
      background-position:0 -125px;      /* <========= HERE */
      height:88px;                       /* <========= AND HERE */
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.game {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.game .slice {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/rdx8FHt.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.game .slice.top_estrada {
  background-position:0 -125px;      /* <========= HERE */
  height:88px;                       /* <========= AND HERE */
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="slice top_estrada">
    top_estrada
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not clear what issue is, can you create a snippet with HTML and CSS that show the issue.

Comment: You can crop the image and then apply as background.

Comment: added jsfiddle example

Comment: my goal is to show only the road, not other parts of image

Comment: it is because of background size

Comment: I need image covering 100% width

Comment: Don't use an image for this, use a gradient or something similar. looks better and scales better

Comment: @cloned I need image cause it covers other aspects of the map (grass, walls, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use percentage. Keep the size with pixel, enable the repeat then adjust the position like you want:

```css
.game {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.game .slice {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/rdx8FHt.png');
  background-size: auto 350px;
}

.game .slice.top_estrada {
  background-position:0 -155px;      
  height:88px;                       
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="slice top_estrada">
    top_estrada
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the size completely and the default size of the image will be used:

```css
.game {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.game .slice {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/rdx8FHt.png');
}

.game .slice.top_estrada {
  background-position:0 -155px;      
  height:88px;                       
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="slice top_estrada">
    top_estrada
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, i have changed the background-size and background position property, with this you can make some adjustments to achieve what you want.

```
  .game{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  .slice{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/rdx8FHt.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    &.top_estrada{
      background-position:0 60%;      // <========= HERE
      height:88px;                       // <========= AND HERE
    }
  }
}
```